# AAD B2C UI Customization - MS content not appearing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I'm trying to use AAD B2C Page UI customization along with Custom Policies as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom. I can get my content to appear, but the standard B2C content does not seem to be merged in as expected.

I have this userjourney in my Extensions.xml file:

```xml
<UserJourney Id="SignInB2CLocal">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
```

and I have this ContentDefinition, also in my Extensions.xml file:

```xml
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <LoadUri>https://kdesteasidmcustom.blob.core.windows.net/LocalSignUI.html</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:idpselection:1.0.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Idp selection page</Item>
          <Item Key="language.intro">Sign in</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>
```

My UI customization file (LocalSignUI.html) as referenced above is very simple:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h1>It worked!</h1>
    <div id="api"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

www.test-cors.org seems to think that CORS is set up correctly for my content file.  When I try to run the userjourney (using the path per the Azure AADB2C portal) I get a page that displays "It worked!" (from my html content file), "Sign in" (not sure where this originates but perhaps from the ContentDefinition "language.intro" key), and nothing else - rest of page is blank.  If I examine page source, there is lots of javascript and a few tags to cover no-cookie and no-javascript scenarios, but there are no form or input tags.  I've looked at the log info in application insights and see a reference to my content file but no apparent errors.

Any ideas?

thanks!

Martin

Comment: If you open the browser developer tools, then are they are console error messages?

Comment: Nothing in Chrome.  Firefox shows a warning `Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead` and identifies 
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:1 as the code location.

Comment: Can you share a url for your policy?  I tried your exact html content on a built-in unified policy and it worked.  [See here](https://login.microsoftonline.com/spottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_Test-Branding-Unified&client_id=d39bf8bf-dc0a-47c6-8c55-fb0aada53d23&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login).

Comment: Also tried pointing a unified built-in policy at your content and it worked.  [See here](https://login.microsoftonline.com/spottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SO-Herbener&client_id=d39bf8bf-dc0a-47c6-8c55-fb0aada53d23&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login)

Comment: @spottedmahn - the URL for my policy is https://login.microsoftonline.com/MBHB2C.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_signin_B2CLocal&client_id=b79e01a8-31d9-4561-9f2f-90fd7ec4d67d&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44316&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login. I too see the expected content when I look at the URL you created.  So presumably something is wrong with my policy?

Comment: Yes, I would think so.  In the http get response I see `<div id="api" data-name="IdpSelections">` not `<div id="api" data-name="Unified">`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved thanks to hint from @spottedmahn!  In my TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file, I created a ContentDefinition (within BuildingBlocks -> ContentDefinitions) like this:

```xml
 <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
   <LoadUri>URL-OF-MY-CUSTOMIZATON-FILE</LoadUri>
   <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
   <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0</DataUri>
   <Metadata>
      <Item Key="DisplayName">Signin and Signup</Item>
   </Metadata>
 </ContentDefinition>
```

The UserJourney's first orchestration step is of Type `CombinedSignInAndSignUp` and ContentDefinitionReferenceID of `api.signuporsignin`.  It appears that 
the `urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0` value for DataUri in the ContentDefinition is key. The Div tag in my customization file contains simply `id="api"`.

thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 0):

I think you need at least a `<head><title></title></head>` otherwise it's not well formed HTML and may not work.

Comment: I modified my HTML file to look like this:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>info</title></head>
<body>
    <h1>It worked!</h1>
    <div id="api"></div>
</body>
</html>`

but result is still the same.